# How to store scraped data in multiple Postregsql tables?

Tags: database, postgresql, scrapy, pipeline

I have one spider that crawls one website, but I want to store the results in two different tables in my Postgresql DB.

1 in "races"
2 in "participants"

If I just fill in one table, it works fine, but how do I get the scrapy pipeline to fill in both tables in one go?

I tried to make two classes in my pipelines.py, but that did not work out. I guess I just miss sth. here

Well, here is my code

```
import logging
import psycopg2
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class RacesPipeline(object):

def open_spider(self, spider):
    
    hostname = 'localhost'
    username = 'postgres'
    password = '****!'
    database = 'horseracing'
    port = "***"
    
    self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, 
    dbname=database, port=port)
    self.cur = self.connection.cursor()

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.cur.close()
    self.connection.close()
    
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.cur.execute("insert into races(track, date, racename, racetype, distancefinal, minalter, maxalter, raceclass, classrating, going, finalhurdle, anzahlstarter, winningtimecombined, pricemoney1, pricemoney2, pricemoney3, pricemoney4, pricemoney5, pricemoney6, pricemoney7, pricemoney8) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        (
        item['track'][0],
        item['date'],
        item['racename'][0],
        item['racetype'],
        item['distancefinal'],
        item['minalter'],
        item['maxalter'],
        item['raceclass'],
        item['classrating'],
        item['going'][0],
        item['finalhurlde'],
        item['anzahlstarter'],
        item['winningtimecombined'],
        item['pricemoney1'],
        item['pricemoney2'],
        item['pricemoney3'],
        item['pricemoney4'],
        item['pricemoney5'],
        item['pricemoney6'],
        item['pricemoney7'],
        item['pricemoney8']
        ))
    self.connection.commit()
    return item

class HorsesPipeline(object):

def open_spider(self, spider):
    
    hostname = 'localhost'
    username = 'postgres'
    password = '********'
    database = 'horseracing'
    port = "****"
    self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database, port=port)
    self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
    

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.cur.close()
    self.connection.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.cur.execute("insert into participants(pos, draw, dwinner, dnext, startnumber, pferde, horsecountry, odd, jockey, trainer, weightkg, alter, headgear, officalrating, rp, ts, rprc) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        (
        item['pos'][0],
        item['draw'],
        item['dwinner'],
        item['dnext'],
        item['startnumber'],
        item['pferde'],
        item['horsecountry'],
        item['odd'],
        item['jockey'],
        item['trainer'],
        item['weightkg'],
        item['alter'],
        item['headgear'],
        item['officalrating'],
        item['rp'],
        item['ts'],
        item['rprc']
        )) 
    self.connection.commit()
    return item
```

And the pipeline settings:

```
 ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'results.pipelines.RacesPipeline': 100,
'results.pipelines.HorsesPipeline':200,
 }
```

If I run the code, I get the **error**
line 33, in process_item
item['track'][0],
KeyError: 'track'

But they run just fine when I don't try to string the two table inserts together, but test them individually. AND, it inserts the first table just fine, even if the error above suggests otherwiese

I **know** I am just missing sth. to add them together, but I can`t figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have TWO different item types. You need to check item instance in your `process_item` and use different `insert`:

```
from your_spider.items import RaceItem, ParticipantItem # use actual names here

    if isinstance(item, RaceItem):
        # insert into race
```

Single `process_item` will work for two different tables, no need to create second `class`.

Comment: Hey, thnaks. I have not defined any items in the *.items file yet, its all in the spider, yielding every item there. How am I going to insert into the tables with this setup? I know this is a very beginner question. I have bought some video turials on how to scrape websites, but they are awefully bad at explaining anything, it is more like "I do this and then this and than that happens" and you can follow along wothout really understanding anything...

Comment: Just use `if "track" in item`

Comment: thank you so much .... and now I am going to learn how to process the data in the items.py and rewrite the spider I have worked on for weeks ;)